How to create metadata .json files for MP4 NFTS?
I have created over 1700 MP4 files that I would like to turn into NFTS. The art and renditions is prepared now how do I attach metadata .json files to each NFT to actually then be able to upload it onto Solana Blockhain. Does Solana even permit .mp4 files as Core Nfts?
Just a background briefing on how I got here. I utilized ChatGPT Dalle to render the images of choice, I then used a Python program that Chat GPT coded to bulk layer the moving emblem over the images. This part was difficult as I have no coding experience and was tweaking the python code for a while to get it right.
Can someone with more experience of releasing NFTS on Solana please provide some help? I have such a cool idea for an NFT project, the art is ready. Yet I have hit an obstacle and for 3 months now have been unable to solve this. Do I really have to code each .json metadata file individually? I was researching machine learning and possibly coding one to learn the traits and rarities of the files.

Solana does allow you to create NFTs with .mp4 files as the core asset.
you can create a vault and store the .mp4 or .jpg on a decentralised storage like Arweave.

also you do not need to manually create each .json file. You can write a Python script to automate the creation of these files.
Here is a template of how your .json should look like
{
  "name": "NFT Name",
  "symbol": "SYMBOL",
  "description": "A description of your NFT",
   //should be the link generate at arweave.net
  "image": "https://link-to-your-image.png",
  "animation_url": "https://link-to-your-video.mp4",
  "attributes": [
    {
     "trait_type": "Background",
     "value": "Blue"
   },
  {
    "trait_type": "Character",
    "value": "Warrior"
  }
  ]
}

you now have to learn how to mint NFTs on Solana ,
This should help Create Tokens and NFTs
